# Deploying different files based on build OS

Tags: travis-ci

I'm deploying build artifacts from Travis to GitHub Releases, but I need to deploy different files depending on the OS the build is performed on. Currently I'm duplicating the `provider` in my `deploy` section and simply adding a condition on TRAVIS_OS_NAME in the on `section`:

```
. . .
deploy
  - provider: releases
    . . .
    file: libsomething.so
    on:
      condition: $TRAVIS_OS_NAME = linux
      . . .
  - provider: releases
    . . .
    file: libsomething.dylib
    on:
      condition: $TRAVIS_OS_NAME = osx
      . . .
```

Is there a more effective way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set an environment variable corresponding to the name of the deployed file.

```
matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      ...
      env: DEPLOY_FILE=libsomething.so
    - os: osx
      ...
      env: DEPLOY_FILE=libsomething.dylib

deploy:
  - provider: releases
    ...
    file: $DEPLOY_FILE
```